While trying to clone my Github repository, the process gets stuck and fails after a matter of time
During the process of cloning my private Github repository to a windows machine within my university network, using SSH, the process gets stuck for a few minutes and fails afterwards. As far as I can tell, because of a disconnect.
I got the information that the IP Address is fully routable and the firewall is not blocking any traffic.
Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and if there is a realistic fix?
This is the Git Debug log:
C:\Users\[User]\Documents\test>set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -v

C:\Users\[User]\Documents\test>git clone git@github.com:SvenDNA/homepage.git
Cloning into 'homepage'...
OpenSSH_9.9p1, OpenSSL 3.2.3 3 Sep 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-cd94d92b7
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-cd94d92b7
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zYCuDer+slWMsl+qHWyrRVWzZqcTSXjdf1KBobFsWGY
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zYCuDer+slWMsl+qHWyrRVWzZqcTSXjdf1KBobFsWGY
debug1: Server accepts key: /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zYCuDer+slWMsl+qHWyrRVWzZqcTSXjdf1KBobFsWGY
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.3]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env GIT_PROTOCOL = "version=2"
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'SvenDNA/homepage.git'
debug1: pledge: fork
remote: Enumerating objects: 910, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (910/910), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (702/702), done.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I tried cloning using SSH and as written above, it did not work.
Cloning using HTTPS worked just fine.

Could be this bug https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/5199

Be advised 2.47.0 is buggy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79078235/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/79094424/7976758
